# Обход reCaptcha v2 картинки

Tags: java, selenium, recaptcha

Использую Selenium. Подскажите, как выбрать картинки, которые даёт reCaptcha v2 от Google?

Comment: Проблемы распознавание капчи, в принципе, не стоят пере Selenium на прямую. Рекомендую обратится к статьям по машинному обучению соответствующего толка, сам пишу тесты на python, и столкнувшись с похожей проблемой нашёл ответ в [этом](http://www.boyter.org/decoding-captchas/)